# Cross-platform usable filesystem with large file support

Tags: filesystems, external-hard-drive, cross-platform

What is the best filesystem to use cross-platform (Linux, Windows, OS X) which supports disk sizes of at least 2TB and file sizes >4GB?

I'm planning to use it on a USB drive on different computers.

Are there any filesystems that can be used on all the named OSes without installing additional drivers?

Comment: More about the environment? Read write? One machine? Network shares?

Comment: read/write support would be great. used as a usb-drive on different computers.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Look at "[OS support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#OS_support)" on the [Comparison of filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#OS_support) page on Wikipedia.  This lists OS support by file system.

As you can see, there is no file system that is covers *all* OS platforms, the closest being FAT16.  FAT32 is a close 2nd, requiring 3rd party driver support for z/OS.

Since you require read/write support and large files and file systems, the best option would be NTFS.  Obviously, Windows OSs support NTFS.  Modern Linux kernels (2.2+) can read and write NTFS natively.  OS X supports reading NTFS natively and writing with [NTFS-3G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G).

Comment: I'm tempted to point out that that table omits AmigaOS :) (That said, I'm giving you +1)

Comment: I'd like to propose exFAT as another solid option, mainly because getting Linux to read/write exFAT is easier than getting OSX to read/write NTFS.

Comment: @JoelESalas Agreed. exFAT works out of the box with OSX and Windows, and on Ubuntu all that is required is a simple `sudo apt-get -y install exfat-utils exfat-fuse`

Comment: I would avoid exFAT. There's no backup of the file allocation table like FAT32 has; with the lack of journaling, one unsafe removal, or system freeze, during a write operation is going to hose the entire drive.

Comment: +1 for the link to NFTS-3G. I didn't know there was an open-source NTFS driver for Mac OS.

Comment: @keltari while Linux 2.2+ has *limited* write support - see `Linux can reliably read NTFS and can overwrite existing files, but the Linux kernel can’t write new files to an NTFS partition.`, an excerpt from [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177978/how-does-linux-kernel-deal-with-windows-ntfs-filesystem), which also explains how linux reads / writes to NTFS in modern times. it's definitely not the kernel driver though.

Comment: `NTFS` is supported by `linux`, but performance is **very** poor.

Comment: Paragon's NTFS3 driver supports full R/W on NTFS disks. It's included in Linux kernel since 5.15. See [NTFS3 in kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/filesystems/ntfs3.html) and [NTFS3 Linux driver FAQ in Paragon Software](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs3-driver-faq/).

Comment: "I would avoid exFAT."  -- objections against exFAT when compared to FAT32 is mostly a myth but I fear it will be around for the years to come non-the-less.

Answer (score 1):

exFAT is now supported as R&W by [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/249972/311449) (via the Linux kernel), [macOS](https://iboysoft.com/wiki/exfat-on-mac.html#:%7E:text=Unlike%20the%20NTFS%20file%20system%20which%20is%20read-only,all%20can%20recognize%20and%20mount%20exFAT%20external%20devices.), and Windows. I believe that that amount of support is able to be reasonably construed as support by every important OS.