# Some folders and/or files on external HDD are accessible on Linux but not on macOS and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, mac, external-hard-drive, files-folders

I have saved some videos on an external NTFS drive that my Linux system can see just fine.

When trying to use a macOS for the same purpose a folder I was looking for was simply missing. I didn’t have a Linux computer with me at the time so I tried to access that folder with a friend’s computer running Windows 10.

The folder was visible on Windows 10 but the videos wouldn’t play with an error saying:

> “…the directory name is invalid.”

That said, the videos could be copied to and played from the Windows internal drive.

Trying later to rename folders in Windows, I get this message:

> “This is no longer located in "/media/cip/TOSHIBA_1TB/CINEMA/American_canada-australia/Charlie Chaplin" verify the item location and try again.”

The folder path has no odd character (I'll rename all folders of the path in Linux anyway and report back). Some of the video files have French names with accented characters but that shouldn't be a problem: the Mac was all in French with all its files and folders in French anyway, and other files and folders in French from other external drive are accessible.

---

What could be the reason? What can be done to allow them to be visible on macOS systems?

I have tested again with another macOS system and the folder still cannot be seen. Will try to test again on Windows and update when I can.

---

**EDIT**: I have removed the NTFS reference from the title, as the problem was reproduced on drives with other types of formatting.

Comment: I'd suspect illegal characters somewhere in the path (colons, slashes etc). Not quite sure how to check for them because the superset of illegal characters doesn't match the subset of each OS. Specifics of any errors may be useful. Screenshots if you can't copy/paste.

Comment: What @Tetsujin says seems to be correct. Not to be pressure anything, but according to your profile you are in France, correct? I would then assume at least one accented character of some kind in the directory path is choking the works. My best recommendation is when you get it connected on macOS again, open up the Terminal and see if you can navigate to the path starting at the path `/Volumes/`. Something like `ls -la /Volumes/[Your Drive Name]/` and such.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - there is no accented characters in directory path, only in file names. I will edit.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I see no odd characters in folder path, but the video files have French accented characters. I thought about that but the Mac and Windows have French as system language and are full of such file names without problem. I I will rename all folders and trey again. I will edit the question to add more info.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Fixed it! By simply renaming the folders in Linux: changed the names from `FILM/American_canada-australia/Charlie Chaplin` to `CINEMA/US_canada-australia/CHAPLIN`. Which character could have been wrong? The space in `Charlie Chaplin`?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought a space would cause an issue in this day & age, but maybe so. You could re-test by putting a space back in, I guess. (Unless for some bizarre reason it was some other space-like character, but that's a bit far-fetched)

Comment: @Tetsujin - Renaming back to the old name didn't recreate the problem. Maybe it was one of the movie names. I did change the long names of two of them... ( But that I cannot replicate anymore.) *Could a name of a file out of 20 make inaccessible the directory it is in?*  Maybe I should delete this question as the problem is very obscure and was fixed

Comment: I'd leave it here. Even without an answer, someone may find it in future & work through the comments towards a fix - maybe even find the true answer.

Comment: @cipricus Wow! I wonder if there was a a “phantom” character in the original filename? Something like a carriage return or non-breaking space that was handled one way in Linux, but choked on other systems? I think you should post a self-solved answer here just in case that restates and expands on the comment you posted here.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - I have posted an answer in which your last comment might be the closest to an explanation.

Comment: PS: If it means anything, I wonder if reading [Microsoft’s official filename guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) might lead to some insights? I am wondering if there might be a character encoding issue as well? Maybe the path was — for example — Latin-1 to begin with but the other file systems expected UTF-8?

Comment: Given the involvement of other systems, I'd also guess it's the code page/character set. However, internally NTFS stores names as UTF-16 (originally UCS-2, though) and allows a lot more characters than what the Win32 subsystem can access by default. As an example a trailing dot is illegal in Windows file names, yet on a Linux-based file share or a disk that was populated from non-Windows you could end up seeing files that end in a `.`. You could then [use this information](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html) to sidestep internal conversion.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 the information from MS, while true, is a bit lacking. Have a look at the link from my last comment. It provides a lot more detail on the subject matter and also shows that from a Win32 program you can sidestep issues (`\??\...` prefix and so on ...) arising from path name conversions internally. [Path length issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15262110/476371) could of course also be a cause.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I recommend you post your additional answer as a fleshed out answer. The original poster provided a solution for them that wiped out the original issue, but your additional info can be very useful for others visiting this question in the future who might end up in a similar situation.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 just did as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am posting this answer just to say how the problem was solved, thus summing up the [comments made to the original question](https://superuser.com/q/1615281/167207), which might be useful to others.*

---

I have fixed the problem in Linux, where those folders had been created, simply by shortening the title of two or three of the video files, which had long names but no obviously odd characters like commas, brackets etc. I have changed also the folder names — although they had nothing special. Changing them back didn't reproduce the problem.

So, either the folder names had some wrong character that was not visible as such on Linux, or the bad characters in some of the three files that were renamed made the whole folder invisible in Mac and *all* its contains unplayable in Windows.

This is the oddest thing that, before renaming the folders and the three files, *none* of the files were playable in Windows.

It might have been, as [@Giacomo1968 said in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1615281/some-folders-from-external-hard-disk-drive-formatted-as-ntfs-on-linux-are-not-se?noredirect=1#comment2463806_1615281):

> ‘…a “phantom” character in the original filename… Something like a carriage return or non-breaking space that was handled one way in Linux, but choked on other systems.’

The thing is that before fixing the problem I have tried to play in Windows other files than those that were renamed in the end. The phantom character could also have been in the folder names.

---

It happened to me again on a new drive formatted as exFAT with other files in a folder about which an error was reported in Linux by Nemo file manager during copying (something like "cannot create file"), but then in fact all looked fine on Linux. That folder was seen but remained completely inaccessible in Windows (I don't exactly remember the error message , something about file or folder not existing), and it was seen on a Mac, except one single file, that remained invisible. After renaming  in Linux the folder and the file **with the same name** all went normally!

I now suspect that the cause for the initial problem reported in the question, and the creation of a bad 'phantom' character, was **some error during a copying process** or the pasting in title of **text copied from internet pages** (where what looks like a space, for example, is in fact something else). This was suggested to me by the fact that while copying with Double Commander in Linux it reported detailed errors on some names which includes spaces that might have been Tab characters or something similar.

(In order to avoid such errors with copy/paste of selected text from the internet, something like a ["copy text-only" addon for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=copy%20text) might be very useful.)

In the end, the best solution for copying was to use Double Commander in Linux which very clearly indicated the file name that had problems.

Copy/paste of internet text when naming files or folders must be done with caution.

Comment: This is why proprietary technologies like NTFS should only be used as a last resort. Creators of 3rd party implementations like those found in Linux and OSX will never be able to recreate Microsoft's secret implementation 100%

Comment: @svin83 - Is there an alternative format to NTFS to be used on an external drive for it to be accessible on all 3 main OSes, Linux, Windows and Mac? I have just got a new one and was thinking about that.

Comment: Said it in my edit summary but saying it here: Great detective work on this. Regarding why it could be seen in Windows but not played until copying it elsewhere, here is my guess: Windows file explorer might have been able to cope with the odd character or whatever, but the player itself could not see the file. Meaning that you could most likely double-click the video and there would be an attempt to open the file. But then the video playback application would choke on the path and fail to play the file as a result. Regardless, great work.

Comment: Depends on your Windows install. IIRC Win10 WSL2 can access ext4 just fine.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - the thing is that before fixing it  I have tried to play in Windows other files than those that were renamed in the end. The phantom character might have been in the folder names.

Comment: @svin83 - what about mac?

Comment: osxfuse and ext4fuse will let you mount ext4 on Mac OS X

Comment: @cipricus FWIW, based on [this other question](https://superuser.com/q/597431/167207) the recommended cross-platform filesystem is generally… (drumroll) NTFS.

Comment: I'd go ExFAT for relatively painless cross-platform compatibility. Everything should be able to read/write that with no system tweaks. if it's for a movie collection or similar, then file system peccadilloes like odd extra streams (a weird windows thing I've never got my head around) or ACLs won't impede you significantly

Comment: BTW, has anyone tried any of the old fuse structures on a modern macOS like Big Sur? (I haven't all the Macs here are too old) personally I invested in the Paragon versions of all the filesystem compatibility structures, when ntfs-3g etc started to go bad nearly a decade ago.

Comment: @cipricus Also, if you somehow have access to the full, original, and faulty file path, you can check the raw character encoding for the text of that file path using a few simple Linux commands as [explained here on the Unix & Linux SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351899/30848).

Answer (score 4):

The way file/folder names work on Windows is discussed [over on Microsoft's website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). However, that provides only a glimpse of the overall truth.

> NB: I will *not* discuss the aspect of codepage issues which can arise from the way a "foreign" system accesses an NTFS volume. I think this is sufficiently covered in comments and the other answer. I will limit myself largely to the following two aspects:

- [path name length limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15262110/476371)
- character combinations that are hard/impossible to access from Win32 subsystem

As for the file system I will limit myself to NTFS, just like the question. Consider the following comment from the above linked website:

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. **Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface *does not*.**

Now, we need to get some of the terminology straight first. We deal with various ... layers, is probably a suitable term:

- file system, e.g. NTFS
- [NT object manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Object_Manager_(Windows)&oldid=999220565) and other kernel facilities, but when it comes to names *mostly* the object manager
  (if you want to look at it, use a tool like [WinObj](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj))
- Win32 subsystem (this is what the above statement refers to as "Windows shell and user interface")
- Another "meta aspect" would be the OS version, because supported path length can vary

A nice method to play around with this is a Samba share that pretends to be NTFS to the client-side. But a Windows NTFS volume will also do. We'll be on Windows and "play around" from the command line (hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd`, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

### Local NTFS volume

Suppose we wanted to create an invalid file name (notice the trailing dot?!):

```
echo NONSENSE > text.txt.
```

When attempting this, the result will indeed be `test.txt`, *not* `test.txt.`. The Win32 subsystem (csrss.exe) prevented us from doing stupid things. Hmm, interesting, huh?

Consider this other statement:

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>
> `CON`, `PRN`, `AUX`, `NUL`, `COM1`, `COM2`, `COM3`, `COM4`, `COM5`, `COM6`, `COM7`, `COM8`, `COM9`, `LPT1`, `LPT2`, `LPT3`, `LPT4`, `LPT5`, `LPT6`, `LPT7`, `LPT8`, and `LPT9`. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, `NUL.txt` is not recommended.

Hmm, `NUL` sounds like fun. We know that from being a substitute for `/dev/null` on unixoid systems, inherited from DOS times.

```
echo NONSENSE > NUL
```

Oh, right. It's a substitute for `/dev/null`, so the output will get swallowed. But **do not use** sounds so very tempting. So let's use the summed up information from a [Project Zero blog article](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html), section "Local Device".

> #### Brief interlude: `%CD%`
>
> If you're not too familiar with the classic Windows command line (`cmd.exe`), the special variable `%CD%` will give us the absolute path to the current working directory. Keep that in mind for the following section.
> So if you were currently inside `C:\test`, the command `echo %CD%` would yield the output `C:\test`. It's a convenient shortcut for out experiments.

As we can glean from the Project Zero article, there are a number of ways to dodge path name conversions at the Win32 subsystem level. One such method is the prefix `\\?\` which internally *directly* translates to `\??\`, which on newer Windows versions is identical to `\GLOBAL??\`. This is called an object directory (please don't confuse it with *file system entities*, despite the similar terminology!). Again, WinObj, and similar tools let you investigate the object manager name space.

> #### Interlude: namespaces and terminal server "stuff"
>
> Whoever has had a look into Windows NT history, and Windows 10 traces its roots back to NT, will remember a time when you had to separately license terminal services. I.e. the ability to connect to a single machine remotely with different users.
>
> I think it was Windows XP which brought this finally for the masses by way of allowing to stay logged on with multiple user accounts simultaneously ("user switching"), and probably Windows 2000 or 2003 Server included this in the standard edition, even though CALs were needed beyond the minimum "seats" included by default.
>
> This is where the distinction between `\??` and `\GLOBAL??` originates. `\GLOBAL??` is the view of the "DOS" device names shared by *all* logon sessions.
>
> `\??` is nowadays seen in the symbolic link (again, *not a file system entity!*) called `\DosDevices`, which gives a clue as to its origin. This is where the "DOS" device names, such as `C:` or network drive mappings reside. On a modern system `C:` in turn would be a symbolic link to `\Device\HarddiskVolume1` (or similar). That is then usually an *actual* device object which was created by some driver in the storage driver stack, in this case it *should* be the NTFS file system driver.
>
> So when you double click `C:\Windows\explorer.exe` what happens internally is that the path gets converted:
>
> - At the Win32 subsystem level the usual change will be to prepend `\??\`.
> - The object manager will then expand the `\??\C:`.
>
>   - First `\??\` ends up in the "DOS" device namespace for your logon session (see remark below)
>   - Eventually the object manager figures out something like `\??\C:` being equivalent to `\GLOBAL??\C:` which - as we saw above - is equivalent to `\Device\HarddiskVolume1`.
>
> The object manager will then pass the remainder of the path `\Windows\explorer.exe` to the driver responsible for device object `\Device\HarddiskVolume1`, making sure the driver knows which device object was referenced. And that driver will know how inside its own namespace to handle that particular remainder of the path.
>
> **Remark:** When you refer to `\??` internally you end up with a view of your local logon session's "DOS" devices. This can best be explained with mapped network drives. Say you have a drive letter `X:` mapped for a remote share. And say you make use of "user switching" or this is running on a beefy terminal server where another two hundred users are concurrently logged on. We have two issues at hand in such a scenario. While the system drive (e.g. physical disk) may be shared by everyone, someone from sales may have mapped "*the* sales share" as `X:` and someone from development may have mapped "*the* development share". The same holds for a "drive letter" assigned via `subst`. This should explain why there cannot be a single global namespace for "DOS" device names, which fits everyone.

So our goal was to create a *file* (or directory) named `NUL` and the Win32 subsystem didn't let us. It simply swallowed the output and the file was never created in our working directory. Leveraging the information from the above linked article and the previous interlude, however, we can work around this by sidestepping those pesky path conversions at the subsystem level by issuing a:

```
echo NONSENSE > \\?\%CD%\NUL
```

As a reminder, `%CD%` expands to the absolute path of the current working directory and, assuming that's `C:\test`, the above command is equivalent to `echo NONSENSE > \\?\C:\test\NUL`.

And lo and behold, a quick `dir` proves the file was created. And if we try that with other "reserved" names, it works fine as well.

Please note that you can also use the *actual* native NT path form (`\??` instead of `\\?`) for the same effect:

```
echo NONSENSE > \??\%CD%\NUL
```

Neat.

So how about we revisit the trailing dot attempt, but giving the full path without having the Win32 subsystem interfere?:

```
echo ILLEGAL TRAILING DOT > \??\%CD%\test.txt.
```

Voila, it works, as a quick `dir /b` proves:

```
C:\test>dir /b
CON
NUL
test.txt
test.txt.
```

> #### Interlude: UNC (Universal Naming Convention) paths
>
> This topic is handled in more detail over in that Project Zero article, but suffice it to say that there is a special form of path which looks quite similar to what we just used above: `\\.\C:\Windows\explorer.exe` would be an example.
>
> Remember that whenever you're stuck on the logon screen, not remembering the local machine name of the machine, and it defaults to the domain of which it is a member? One easy way to refer to *the current machine* without even using its actual name is `.\username`, allowing to reference the user `username` on *the current machine*.
>
> The `.` in `\\.\C:\Windows\explorer.exe` is to be understood similarly. In effect what you're saying is `\\.` *on the current machine* `\C:` *on drive `C:`* access path `\Windows\explorer.exe` ... and the different facilities of the OS tie into each other to make it happen.
>
> *Beware*: UNC paths follow a different set of rules, which is why I only mention them. Read the linked article and the link to Microsoft documentation if you are interested in more details.

Now that we have finally created an "impossible" file `test.txt.`, let's have a look at it, shall we?

```
C:\test>type test.txt
NONSENSE
```

What the heck? I clearly recall having echoed `ILLEGAL TRAILING DOT` into that file.

Ah, of course. Just like when we initially tried to create `test.txt.` the Win32 subsystem intervened again and "helpfully" converted our name to `test.txt`. So we're actually looking at `\??\%CD%\test.txt` instead of `\??\%CD%\test.txt.`.

So this should do:

```
C:\test>type \??\%CD%\test.txt.
ILLEGAL TRAILING DOT
```

Much better. The problem is that not all programs will handle our sneaky sidestepping of the Win32 path name conversions as gracefully as `cmd.exe`. Suppose we wanted to open Notepad:

```
C:\test>notepad \??\%CD%\test.txt.
```

Dang, we get to see the following message box:

[image: Warning message box saying: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.]

So while there are ways you can circumvent *some* of the restrictions imposed by the Win32 subsystem, the utility of these methods is limited and questionable.

**Note**: Readers who also *develop* software on/for Windows may recall that using the prefix `\\?\` allowed to sidestep the `MAX_PATH` limit (used to be 260, basically 255 plus `\\?\` and a terminating `\0`). Now you know why this allows us to make use of [*approximately* 32767 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15262110/476371). Since UCS-2 was replaced with UTF-16 (I think in XP), the path mangling at the object manager level is but one issue. Another is that in UTF-16 a code point may take up more than 16 bit (aka `wchar_t` or `WCHAR`), once you leave the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) behind.

Anyway, the command line (`cmd.exe`) gives you all of the tools to access and get rid of files which you were able to create from Windows in the first place.

### Linux/Samba share, pretending to be NTFS

Let's now depart from the local drive and consider a mapped network drive `Z:`, provided by Samba 4.x, which mimics an NTFS drive as far as Windows is concerned.

[image: Drive properties for a mapped network drive Z:, showing that Windows considers this to be an NTFS drive]

This experiment offers a few more insights, because we can create files according to the rules of the Linux side and don't have to be anxious about being unable to access them from the Windows side.

- The mapped drive is `Z:` and we'll be in `Z:\test` on the Windows side
- On the Linux side the volume was formatted as [btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs)
  The Wikipedia article tells us all characters other than `/` and `\0` (aka [ASCII NUL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart)) are allowed! So this should be fun.

Here are some extravagant file names which should (or at least could) be hard to access on the Windows side, using Bash on Ubuntu 20.04 on the Linux side to create them:

- `:.txt` (created with `echo "$RANDOM" > \:.txt`)
- `???.txt` (created with `echo "$RANDOM" > \?\?\?.txt`)
- `.txt` (created with `echo "$RANDOM" > .txt`)
- `*.txt` (created with `echo "$RANDOM" > \*.txt`)
- `\.txt` (created with `echo "$RANDOM" > \\.txt`)
- `".txt` (created with `echo "$RANDOM" > \".txt`)
- `>.txt` (created with `echo "$RANDOM" > \>.txt`)
- `<.txt` (created with `echo "$RANDOM" > \<.txt`)
- `|.txt` (created with `echo "$RANDOM" > \|.txt`)

This should pretty much cover all bases, actually on second thought the emoji may not even be an issue at all. Forward slashes are also forbidden on NTFS, but that holds true for btrfs/[POSIX/SUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification) as well.

Proof from the Linux side:

```
$ find -type f -printf '%P\n'
:.txt
???.txt
.txt
*.txt
\.txt
".txt
>.txt
<.txt
|.txt
```

Now let's see if and what we can access on the Windows side ...

```
Z:\test>dir /b
_2X68P~X.TXT
_2X68Q~5.TXT
_2X68Q~9.TXT
_2X68Q~B.TXT
_2X68Q~D.TXT
_2X68R~7.TXT
_2X68S~3.TXT
_67V3K~2.TXT
.txt
```

Screenshot as proof:

[image: Windows Command Prompt showing the contents of the share with illegal file names from the Windows side]

Ohhhhh! Right, the DOS heritage of Windows strikes again. NTFS - [unless actively disabling it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name) - has the ability to create so-called 8.3 short file names, conforming to the DOS file name requirements.

And that's how we are able to access the invalid file names regardless.

### Conclusion

Now recall, the question was about an external, i.e. local, NTFS drive. This means the rules we just observed for Samba shares may not apply here.

Depending on the driver used to store these files (which could vary by Linux/macOS version, e.g. ntfs-3g or the third-party driver used, e.g. Paragon's driver) I see the following possible causes left after looking at the above experiments:

1. the file name contained a `:`, `"` or `?` ... this seems the most likely to me, given I'd had accidentally copied and pasted ebook titles myself, containing these characters. We can pretty much rule out `/` and the other "forbidden" characters are at least less likely.
2. the Windows and macOS side see the invalid name, attempt to look at the DOS 8.3 name, but none was generated. This somewhat depends on the exact Windows version and its configuration and since I have no macOS devices around, I cannot test that scenario either. Also, I am not sure whether on a Windows system where 8.3 names *are enabled* Windows would retroactively go and generate a 8.3 name if, say, the Linux side skipped that part. Because if I recall correctly [the NTFS driver decides whether the respective record ("attribute") gets populated](https://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-files-types.htm).
3. the length of the path name was exceeded. I think exceeding the length of path segments is an impossibility, because NTFS doesn't let you store more than 255 16-bit values for a path segment, but the overall path length may also have been exceeded (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15262110/476371)).

For the first scenario, I would recommend using [fslint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/) on the Linux side to sanitize the file (and folder) names. Other similar tools exist and YMMV, take a pick.

Hope this helps. It took long enough to dump my thoughts into writing.

---

#### Further reading

- [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html)
- [The Definitive Guide on Win32 to NT Path Conversion](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html)